# RuntimeError: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported using nll_loss

Tags: pytorch, artificial-intelligence

Trying to calculate loss (using nll_loss) and confusion matrix, but I am getting the following error:

> RuntimeError: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported

I am aware that there are some suggestions online to solve my issue, but none has worked so far.

This is my code snippet:

```
def test_persionalized_model(self):
        self.model.eval()
        cTC = 0
        cP = []
        #test_acc = 0
        self.update_parameters(self.persionalized_model_bar)
        for x, y in self.testloaderfull:
            x, y = x.to(self.device), y.to(self.device)
            output = self.model(x)
            #test_acc += (torch.sum(torch.argmax(output, dim=1) == y)).item()
            cm = confusion_matrix(y, torch.argmax(output, dim=1))
            TC = np.diag(cm)
            cTC += np.sum(TC)
            for i in range (0,len(cm[0])):
              cP.append(cm[i][i]/(np.sum(cm[i])+1e-7))
        self.update_parameters(self.local_model)
        return cTC, np.sum(cm), cP
```

Line: 9

Error backtrace:
[image]

output shape: ([101705, 11])

y shape: ([101705, 11])

I am expecting the code snippet to calculate the confusion matrix and loss. I have tried reshaping, flatening, but none solved my issue.

Comment: That was a typo. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

"multi-target not supported" seems to refer to the target *i.e* `y_true` being in one-hot-encoding format while it is supposed to be in dense format. In other words a 1D tensor containing the true class indices. You could try something like:

```
cm = confusion_matrix(y.argmax(1), output.argmax(1))
```

Comment: That seems to fix my confusion_matrix error. However, I am still stuck at calculating the loss. I tried using your method when calculating the loss, but I got another error saying that I need to pass a tensor and not a numpy array.

Comment: Well, that is another error. Please provide additional info

Comment: It is the same error I mentioned in the post: RuntimeError: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported

Comment: Please provide the exact line and the corresponding (full) error backtrace

Comment: Since it won't look proper in the comment, I will post it in the original post. Edit: posted

Comment: You are not showing the relevant code.